# How to pass UIViewController as a parameter swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a common method for that i have to pass self(current UIViewController ) as a parameter. Below is the method:

```
  func getFBUserData(){

        if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current(){

        print("Access Token: \(token.tokenString!)")

            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dict)
                    var jsonObj = JSON(result!)
                    if let first_name = jsonObj["first_name"].string {
                        NSLog("first_name : \(first_name)")
                    }
                    NSLog("RESULT JSON : \(JSON(result!))")
                    //print("Access Token: \(FBSDKAccessToken.current())")
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

I modified this as follows:

```
func IsFaceBookPermisssionGranted(_ completion: @escaping (_ IsPermissionGranted: Bool, _ error_type:ErrorType)->()) {

    let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: UIViewController?) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    completion(true,nil)
                }
            }else{
                completion(false,.AUTH_FAILED)
            }
        }else{
            print("Error : \(error)")
            completion(false,.AUTH_FAILED)
        }
    }
}
```

But when i pass UIViewController like above it says 
Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController!'

What can i do on this ?

Comment: Try UIViewController.self

Comment: Simply try with self.

Comment: Instead of UIViewController?, pass the ViewController Object, which in your case will be `self` . It is better to create a weak reference of the current View Controller and then pass it to avoid a strong reference.       

    `weak var weakself = self  
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from:weakself)`

Comment: where is this method IsFaceBookPermisssionGranted(_ completion:) created, is it in separate class? or inside UIViewController subclass?

Comment: @NiravD I'm calling this in a viewController. But i want to make this method in a common class. By initiating that class in a ViewController i want to call this method.

Comment: @NiravD Exactly, I want to reuse it.

Comment: @suhi Yes It is in separate class which i want to reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

**In swift 3.0,**
you cannot pass directly your UIViewController.
First you can create a view controller object.

For example,

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let yourVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your_view_controller_Identifier") as! YourViewController
```